# Flush property of a NULL object

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, null

I'm new on stackoverflow and in symfony development.

Summary of the problem :

I get value from my Ajax in the controller with Request $request.
When I'm doing a var_dump of my object ($donate), it returns me all the data. But when I want to flush, it says me that one of my property is to NULL (projectID)?

Can somebody help me ? Thx a lot and sorry for my English.

```
class AjaxController extends Controller
    {
        public function addDonationAction(Request $request)
        {

            $projectID = (int)$request->request->get('projectID');


            $donate = new Donate();
            $donate->setAmount($request->request->get('donationAmount'));
            $donate->setProjectID($projectID);
            $donate->setUserID(1); // Faudra récupérer tout ça du user connecté !

            // var_dump($donate); die();

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($donate);
            $em->flush();

            // Faire tous les contrôles
            // Envoie en DB si tout est ok
            // Mise à jour : projectT
            // Insert : donateT
            return new JsonResponse($donate);
        }
    }
```

## FOR FRENCH PEOPLE

Bonjour,

Je suis nouveau sur stackoverflow et débutant en développement symfony2.

Un petit résumé de mon souci :
Je récupère des valeurs dans mon controller suite à une requête Ajax. Quand je fais un var_dump, il m'indique bien mes valeurs. Par contre si je veux insérer en DB, il ne trouve pas une valeur et me dit que c'est NULL (projectID). Ci-dessous le code controller :

```
class AjaxController extends Controller
{
    public function addDonationAction(Request $request)
    {

        $projectID = (int)$request->request->get('projectID');


        $donate = new Donate();
        $donate->setAmount($request->request->get('donationAmount'));
        $donate->setProjectID(1);
        $donate->setUserID(1); // Faudra récupérer tout ça du user connecté !

        // var_dump($donate); die();

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($donate);
        $em->flush();

        // Faire tous les contrôles
        // Envoie en DB si tout est ok
        // Mise à jour : projectT
        // Insert : donateT
        return new JsonResponse($donate);
    }
}
```

Si vous pouviez m'éclairez ou me donner une piste, je vous serais très reconnaissant.

PS : je travaille en local :-(

Merci à tous !!

Comment: In English please / En anglais SVP.

Comment: You may be interested in supporting the Area 51 proposal, [Programmation (Stack Overflow in French)](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/63820/programmation-stack-overflow-in-french)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not written in English. Apologies for this restriction - it would be good to have SO in other languages.

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is to read carefully (and work the examples) in the Symfony Doctrine documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html

You have not quite grasped the fact that Doctrine 2 is an Object Relation Manager.  Hence the incorrect use of projectId and userId.

You should have three objects: Donate,Project,User with the proper relations setup.  You would then build your Donate object using references to Project and User.

```
$projectID = (int)$request->request->get('projectID');  // Be sure to check that you have a id
$userID    = $this->getUser()->getId(); // Or wherever your user object comes from

$projectReference = $em->getReference('MyBundle:Project',$projectID);
$userReference = $em->getReference('MyBundle:User',$userID);

$donate->setProject($projectReference);
$donate->setUser($userReference);
```

Note that if user is always the currently logged in user then there is no need to make a reference.  Just pass the user object.